# R - Function to create a data.frame containing manipulated data from another data.frame

Tags: r

Hi I am new to R and have a question. I have a data.frame (df) containing about 30 different types of statistics from years 1960-2012 for about 100 different countries. Here is an example of what it looks like:

```
     Country      Statistic.Type     1960      1961      1962      1963 ...  2012 
__________________________________________________________________________________
1    Albania      Death Rate          10        21        13        24        25  
2    Albania      Birth Rate          7         15        6         10        9  
3    Albania      Life Expectancy     8         12        10        7         20  
4    Albania      Population          10        30        27        18        13
5    Brazil       Death Rate          14        20        22        13        18
6    Brazil       Birth Rate          ...  
7    Brazil       Life Expectancy     ...  
8    Brazil       Population          ...  
9    Cambodia     Death Rate          ...  
10   Cambodia     Birth Rate          ...                  etc...
```

Note that there are 55 columns in total and the values in each of the 53 year columns are made up for the purposes of this question.

I need help writing a function which takes as inputs the country and statistic type and returns a new data.frame with 2 columns which shows the year and value in each year for a given country and statistic type. For example, if I input country=Brazil and statistic.type=Death Rate into the function, the new data.frame should look like:

```
     Year    Value 
_____________________
1    1960     14
2    1961     20
3    1962     22
...
51   2012     18
```

I have no idea on how to do this, if anyone can give me any ideas/code/packages to install then that would be very helpful.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please read this and provide a minimal reproducible example of your data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @user2397274, could you please consider accepting one of the answers below if you believe your question has been satisfactorily answered? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If `df` is your data.frame, all you need is this:

```
f <- function(country, statistic.type, data=df)
{
 values <- data[data$Country==country & data$Statistic.Type==statistic.type,-(1:2)]

 cbind(Year=names(df)[-(1:2)], Value=values)
}
```

Use it as

```
f(country="Brazil", statistic.type="Death Rate")
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to do some split operation on the total data set to have country individual datasets.
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-February/155328.html

Then use the melt function for each subset of data. In your case, adapted from 
http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html, where mydata is the already splitted data:

```
    % example of melt function 
    library(reshape)
    mdata <- melt(mydata, id=c("Year"))
```

That is it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just combine `subset` with `stack`, with maybe a `gsub` in there to leave only the numbers in your column of years:

```
df <- expand.grid(
  "country" = c("A", "B"),
  "statistic" =  c("c", "d", "e", "f"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$year1980 <- rnorm(8)
df$year1990 <- rnorm(8)
df$year2000 <- rnorm(8)


getYears <- function(input, cntry, stat) {
  x <- subset(input, country == cntry & stat == statistic,
    select = -c(country, statistic))
  x <- stack(x)[,c("ind", "values")]
  x$ind <- gsub("\\D", "", x$ind)
  x
}


getYears(df, "A", "c")

   ind     values
1 1980  1.1421309
2 1990  1.0777974
3 2000 -0.2010913
```